# Changing image on click Raphael paper

Tags: raphael

I have a program where the user can add images to a paper, using Raphael. Now I want to be able to change an image to another image when clicked. Is this possible? Do I have to add an ID to the images? If so, how?

```
        var imgURL = "img/img.png";

        var bankNoteImg = new Image();
        bankNoteImg.src = imgURL;

        var width = bankNoteImg.width;
        var height = bankNoteImg.height;

        var image = paper.image(imgURL, X, Y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [click](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.click) and [attr](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr) function of Raphael api.

Element.click will take a function as a parameter. Use `this` to access the image element inside the function.

I created a simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kf0jn9rd/)

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("papercanvas"), 200, 200);
var img = paper.image(URL1, 100, 100, 100 , 100);

function changeImageSource() {
    this.attr('src', URL2);
}

img.click(changeImageSource);
```

Comment: This seem to fix my problem! Thank you sir!